# NHibernate or FluentNHibernate or ActiveRecord?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, activerecord, fluent-nhibernate

I am in a stage of mapping my CSharp classes into database tables. I have decided to use NHibernate as my ORM tool after comparing with other tools. I have never done a real project with NHibernate before and now am considering alternatives for the mapping,

ActiveRecord: according to the project's web site, using ActiveRecord can boost productivity dramatically. However, I do not like the idea of adding attributes to my CSharp classes. After all, my class should NOT have any knowledge of database relationships. By using ActiveRecord will bind my nicely separated classes to ActiveRecord, and give me hard time if I ever want to switch underline DAO Layer implementation in the future.

FluentNHibernate: FluentNhibernate was my first attempt when starting mapping. But I also have a few issues with this approach. 1) I don't like my mapping strategies compiled as binary files. I would like to be able to change mapping by modifying xml files. 2) The maturity of FluentNHibernate.  NHibernate has been around for a long time, and has LOTS of users, so I am quite comfortable with its maturity. On the contrast, FluentNhibernate is relatively young and not been tested by as many users. Even though I could dive into the source to fix whatever issue comes up, I am not comfortable with my skills to touch the low level implementation. 3) Availability of documentation for FluentNHibernate is much than that of NHibernate. I would like to have a place to go when I hit a hard wall.

NHibernate: Currently, I am using naked Nhibernate xml to do the mapping. To be honest, working with XML gives me massive headaches. Literally, I have to keep myself from the impulsion of just throwing away the .hbm.xml files and grab ActiveRecord or FluentNHibernate several times a day.

So, here is my dilemma: Should I go with my heart of "Just get this damn thing done!"; Or, should I follow the "Good practice guideline" to suffer the pain now and get relatively easy time later on?

Any comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that any classes related to an ORM should not necessary be treated as "business object" classes or exposed to your UI.  They should be considered part of your data layer.  This pattern is not really unique to ActiveRecord.  In general, you want your business layer to know as little as possible regarding the fact that there is an ORM beneath it, and you don't want your UI to know about your data layer.  You also want to consider [DTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

Fluent NHibernate solves the problem of having weakly typed XML which can be error prone to refactor.

While there can be downsides of adopting something like ActiveRecord, it seems like an appropriate solution in your case.

The best reason to use .hbm.xml files is if you are going to code generate them from your database (using something like [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/)).  Hand coding the .hbm.xml files is rarely the best option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will go with ActiveRecord for now.