# Castle ActiveRecord Mapping problem

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

As the result of [yesterday's discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469703/nhibernate-or-fluentnhibernate-or-activerecord) , I have decided to use Castle ActiveRecord for my ORM task. I have added attributes to the class according to the [starting guide](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/index.html). After fixing some obvious errors, I was greeted with this:

***Could not find configuration for CLASS_XXX or its root type Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase this is usually an indication that the configuration has not been setup correctly***

Where CLASS_XXX in the error message is one of my c# class name. What is interesting is that CLASS_XXX is different each time I run the code. I have turned on log4net and my log.txt captured nothing. So, I am guessing the error occurred before the process reaches NHibernate.

Following is my CSharp code

```
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        InPlaceConfigurationSource source = 
                new InPlaceConfigurationSource();


        Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("DomainModel.Entities");

        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(asm,source);
        ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema();
```

Any suggestion for finding the real cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you're missing the configuration for the `InPlaceConfigurationSource` ([sample](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk/ActiveRecord/Castle.ActiveRecord.Tests/InvalidRootTypeTestCase.cs)) or you need to use a [different initialization method](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/initandtest.html).

Comment: The link you provided to "sample" was actually incorrect. It points to the "InvalidRootTypeTestCase", which is supposed to throw Exception.  However, this link gives me a GREAT start point--Tests for the source. This is the first time I actually use tests as the primary documentation. I downloaded all the source and read the tests, and it turned out that it was indeed an initialization problem. All I need is a simple var source = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("activerecord") as IConfigurationSource; And things started getting together. Thank for the direction.

Comment: the link is not incorrect... it shows how to programmatically configure a InPlaceConfigurationSource

Answer (score 1):

This is not likely correct:

```
InPlaceConfigurationSource source = new InPlaceConfigurationSource();
```

You need to either do something like this:

```
string connectionString =
  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ToString();
InPlaceConfigurationSource source =
  InPlaceConfigurationSource.Build(
    DatabaseType.MSSQLServer2005, connectionString
  );
```

Or something like this:

```
string connectionString =
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
      ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ToString();
IDictionary<string, string> properties =
  new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
properties.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect");
properties.Add("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver");
properties.Add("connection.provider",
  "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
properties.Add("connection.connection_string", connectionString);
properties.Add("proxyfactory.factory_class",
  "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle");

InPlaceConfigurationSource source = new InPlaceConfigurationSource();
source.Add(typeof(ActiveRecordBase), (IDictionary<string, string>)properties);
```

Comment: Your point is right. It's the initialization for source that caused the problems. However, since it was Mauricio Scheffer's link took me to the right place for finding the problem. I had to mark his advise as answer. Thanks for your great help, though.